# Abbreviation page not generated / using nomencl

Tags: templates, nomenclature

I am using:

1. TeXstudio on a macbook.
2. The following document class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index
]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
```

**Preamble:** I added this to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{ Notations and Abbreviations}
```

I also tried:

```
 \usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
```

**Main tex file:** and this to the main tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
\input{Preamble/preamble}
\input{thesis-info}

\ifdefineAbstract
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \includeonly{Declaration/declaration, Abstract/abstract}
\fi

\ifdefineChapter
 \includeonly{Chapter3/chapter3}
\fi
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
  \maketitle
\end{titlepage}


\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

% \printnomenclature[space] space can be set as 2em between symbol and description
%\printnomenclature[3em]

\printnomenclature

\mainmatter

\include{Chapter1/chapter1}
\include{Chapter2/chapter2}
\include{Chapter3/chapter3}
\begin{spacing}{0.9}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\cleardoublepage
\bibliography{References/references}
\end{spacing}
\printthesisindex % If index is present

\end{document}
```

**Inside different chapters:** and this in-text (in different chapters/ different files) whenever I have an abbreviation:

```
\nomenclature{TI}{This is IT}%
```

The abbreviation page is not generated. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Edit 3:
P.S: I did run the 'pdflatex' and 'index' (make index) multiple times.

and I always get:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2015] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file thesis.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in thesis.ind.
Transcript written in thesis.ilg.
```

Edit 2:

Can you please tell me if I am using 'nomencl' correctly? process/sequence/strucutre-wise? I followed different examples online, I did the exact same thing. 
I suspect that the predefined .cls file (PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls) for the template found on https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/releases/tag/v2.1 
is causing a difference in the way 'nomencl' is used.

Edit 1:
As I am waiting for answer, I went to the .cls file and I found the following:

```
% ******************************* Nomenclature *********************************
\RequirePackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{\item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Z}}{\item[\textbf{Acronyms / Abbreviations}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{\item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{\item[\textbf{Other Symbols}]}
{}
}% matches mathematical symbols > X
}% matches Subscripts           > S
}% matches Superscripts         > R
}% matches Abbreviations        > Z
}% matches Greek Symbols        > G
}% matches Roman Symbols        > A

% To add nomenclature in the header
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}

% Add nomenclature to contents and print out nomenclature
\newcommand{\printnomencl}[1][]{
\ifthenelse{\equal {#1}{}}
{\printnomenclature}
{\printnomenclature[#1]}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}
}
```

Does it mean I shouldn't add anything to the preamble or what? Am I causing redundancy?

Comment: Please post a compilable example, not just fragments

Comment: It's still not compilable :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yeah I have this on different files, the 'main' file, the 'preamble' file and 3 chapter files. I just want to know the right process/sequence that would generate the abbreviation page. I followed different examples on the web. I think the problem might be in having multiple files... or it could be from the definitions in the .cls file ..

Comment: Apparently you don't understand: You're posting fragments only -- we have no idea what your `.cls` file is or what's in your document

Comment: I understand that you want me to post a compilable file @ChristianHupfer. But my case would require multiple files. Regarding the CLS: it is for a template that is defined here https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/releases/tag/v2.1

Comment: Having multiple files is in most cases no good idea, regardless what others suggest with `\include` and `\includeonly`. Again: Make a copy of your `main` stuff and reduce it the absolute minimum that produces **no** nomenclature page as you requested. There's no need to use other files here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added the main file

Comment: That template is a constant source of utter confusion and a real hindrance for new users. I cannot recommend it.

Comment: When you say you »did run […] 'index'« do you mean you did run »`makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls`« where »`filename`« should be the actual name of your file?

Comment: @clemens yes, I am using texstudio so I go to tools > compile then tools > index then tool >compile again. 
I also tried with TexShop, same steps: typeset> latex, typeset>make index and again typeset > latex. I get this:
`This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2015] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file thesis.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in thesis.ind.
Transcript written in thesis.ilg.`

Comment: Then please try to do the necessary compilation step on the command line! I'd guess that the makeindex entries of editors that you've used simply run `makeindex filename.idx` instead of using the required command options for creating the nomenclature.

Comment: I did that: `HappyBees-MacBook-Pro:~HappyBee$ makeindex thesis.idx`
and I got the following error `Input index file thesis.idx not found.` @clemens

Comment: @HappyBee as I said earlier and as the manual clearly states you must run `makeindex thesid.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o thesis.nls`

Comment: @clemens I did run it as in the manual. However, I just discovered I did not point the terminal to the correct directory. Thank you. Please write your comment from 21 hours ago as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @clemens what do you mean by "instead of using the required command options for creating the nomenclature"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @clemens some editors might run  `makeindex filename.idx` instead of `makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls`
which is required for creating the nomenclature.

So if you have the same problem run the following from the terminal/command line of your system (you also have to navigate to the master file from the command line first):

```
makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls
```

My problem is solved. I hope this helps anyone else.